# Homebrew RVM and Ruby Mac OSx Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

Homebrew does not work anymore. trying brew doctor or brew update command on the terminal getting this error:

```
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb: line 4: `std_trap = trap("INT") { exit! 130 } # no backtrace thanks'
```

XCode 5 and Command Line Tools have already installed!
which brew command result is
brew is /usr/local/bin/brew

(uninstall homebrew then re-installed but still I couldnt install brew formulas)

Comment: add the first 5 lines off `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb`

Comment: tried nothing! guess missing interpreter or something to run properly

Comment: you need to run: `head -n 5 /usr/local/Library/brew.rb` no to execute this file

Answer (score 0):

i think it is just a syntax error, just put the backtick(`) at the end of the 4th line. So the line 4 looks like this

```
      `std_trap = trap("INT") { exit! 130 }`
```

It is a system call, so to run the command or system call, using backtick is one of the solutions.

Comment: no, I dont think so. This is github master source default file content should work like that! [link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)

Comment: maybe just restart the system and reload your profile 'source .profile' , usually that fixes these kind of things.

Comment: ok, added this code on the line 1 : #!/usr/local/bin/ruby -W0 it is correct way run the ruby path I think. Thanks! its working now